# Add Multidimensinal array to an array list using Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I am having a method(function) that is supposed to add a (8*6)Array to an Array list. Function is called several times.

```
int [][] KeySelection = new int [8][7];

  for(int i=0;i<KeySelection.length;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<KeySelection[0].length;j++){
      KeySelection[i][j] = (int) (Math.random () * 2);

     }
  }
```

Each time this function is called a totally new `KeySelection` Array is done. What i need now is to declare an array list so that it could store all the `KeySelection` Arrays in that list.

So that when i need the first `KeySelection` Table i could find it in the first index of the Array list. Could somebody Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `ArrayList` of type `int[][]`: -

```
List<int[][]> list = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
```

And then, add your array to this list after creation: -

```
list.add(keySelection);
```

**NOTE: -** Variable name should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: OK perfect.. now Assume the list is full, when I need to call ,Lets say the first KeySelection Table,, what is the exact syntax

Comment: `int[][] firstMatrix = list.get(0);` Read the [Java tutorial on collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and the [List javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: One More question..Does the "(Math.random () * 2)" add the exact same values to the exact same locations.. so if the function runs twice to i get same KeySelection Tables

Comment: @user1111726.. What do you exactly want to add in those arrays?

Comment: I dont think I really get u there.. but what i am asking.. is that normal to have the two tables identical.. because thats what i wasnt and thats what is happening.. or is it just a conicedence

Comment: @user1111726.. No you won't get the same table there. If you are getting, which is surprising, then its a big coincidence. `Math.random() * 2` generates a value between `0 and 2`. So, typecasting it to `int` will give you either `0 or 1`. And that is totally random.

Comment: OK guys I am having a bit of a problem here.. whenever i add to the Arraylist (list) the new additiion overwrittes all the other causing all entries to be the same as the last.. I have been trying all day, its the same if i use vectors or stacks.. what is going on ?

Answer (score 1):

Since arrays in Java are special type of objects, you can use an ArrayList of objects to hold your arrays. Declare your list like that and populate it via for loop etc.

```
ArrayList<int[][]> list = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
```

Comment: @user1111726 if you don't have such a class, so how your code uses this class ???

Comment: The code doesn't use a KeySelection class, but a variable named KeySelection.

Comment: I edited the question for better understanding.. the method intializes  a new 2-D array called "KeySelection" every time the function is called, new values in the KeySelection table.. What i need is to add them to an array list each time the function is called so at the end I could have a list contating all Arrays of KeySelection

Comment: @JB Nizet.. Yes u got me.. is there a way to add those KeySelection Varaiable to the Arraylist each time the function is called