# Addition to Arraylist overwrites the rest, why is that

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

This question is a followup for this one..

> [Add Multidimensinal array to an array list using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430448/add-multidimensinal-array-to-an-array-list-using-java)

```
  int tmp;
  int[][] Key = new int [TopSubKey.length+BottomSubKey.length][TopSubKey.length];
  int[][] KeyChoiceTable = {{14,17,11,24,1,5},{3,28,15,6,21,10},{23,19,12,4,26,8}}     
 int [][] KeySelection = new int [KeyChoiceTable.length][KeyChoiceTable[0].length];

List<int [][]> list = new ArrayList<int [][]>();


 int row,col,x;

for(int l =0;l<3;l++) {

 for(int i=0;i<KeyChoiceTable.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<KeyChoiceTable[0].length;j++){
         row = 0;
         col = 0;
         x = KeyChoiceTable[i][j];
         while(x>7){x=x-7; row=row+1;}
         col = x-1;

     KeySelection[i][j] = Key[row][col];
     }
 }
 list.add(KeySelection);
 System.out.print(list.size());
  }
```

If you could just have a look.. because the problem seems so stupid but its killing me.

The Lopp runs 2 times, What I am expecting from the last line is for each loop to store the 2D Array in the list at index 0, and therefore the second loop stores the second 2D Keyselection in the list at index 1.
Whenever i add to the Arraylist (list) the new additiion overwrittes all the other causing all entries to be the same as the last.. I have been trying all day, its the same if i use vectors or stacks.. what is going on ?

Comment: Show us your code. Paste it into your question. Try to include the minimum code that still shows the problem.

Comment: If you're asking a question please include the information in the question, rather than referring to an earlier one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `KeySelection` to `list`, you're really adding a reference to it, not a copy. When you change `KeySelection` on the next iteration, the change is also reflected in the `list`. To avoid this, declare `KeySelection` in the same scope as you add it to `list`:

```
for(int l =0;l<3;l++) {
    int [][] keySelection = new int [KeyChoiceTable.length][KeyChoiceTable[0].length];
    // Populate keySelection
    list.add(keySelection);
    System.out.print(list.size());
}
```

Then each entry in `list` is a different Array.

Comment: @RobEarl..You ROCK BIG TIME.. You see that what pisses me off about java.. I have been literlly stuck to my chair all morning trying to solve this and it just required a small change..Thanks again Man

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing an array of objects, you should create a new object to each entry. Don't add an object, then change some instance value, and add them again, this will change all other entries as well. (Read more about the Object Oriented approach of Java).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are manipulating the values in the same array over and over and the ArrayList doesn't make copies of the elements added to it but rather just references them, each entry in the ArrayList refers to the same array, which has the last state, it's given.

Comment: to get a copy of an object use the clone method. btw. in your code example is a missing ; and the loop runs 3 times. also temp is not used.

Comment: Yeah.. I trimmed off parts of the code(tmp).. how are you suggesting to use the clone.I am quite a noob in java and i am trying to crack my way thru but i need more help